# How to remove a nested array object in JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to remove the first object from a nested array but somehow I am not able to delete the first object here is my code can you please help?

```js
var arr = [
        {
          demo: [
            {
              label: "NOT - Notification",
              id: "NOT",
              subTree: null,
            },
            { 
              label: "LIM - Limitation", 
              id: "LIM", 
              subTree: null 
            },
          ],
    },
];
      
var ind = arr.findIndex(function (element) {
  return element.demo?.id === "NOT";
});
if (ind !== -1) {
  arr.splice(ind, 1);
}
console.log('this is new', arr);
```

If you have any better solution then feel free to drop will appreciate your help.

Comment: It is an array inside an object inside an array. Please check again

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: You're calling `splice` on the top-most array, not the array property of the object within the array. Call `splice` on the correct array, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the wrong array dimension. Check each subarray in the array:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        demo: [
            {
                label: "NOT - Notification",
                id: "NOT",
                subTree: null,
            },
            { 
                label: "LIM - Limitation", 
                id: "LIM", 
                subTree: null 
            },
        ],
    },
];

for (const item of arr) {
    const index = item.demo.findIndex(subitem => subitem.id === "NOT");
    if (index >= 0) item.demo.splice(index, 1)
}

console.log('this is new', arr);
```

Comment: There is no "dimension" here... Or rather, there is only a single dimension.

Comment: Since it is a **nested** array, it has two dimensions

Comment: It does not remove a first object if you check in the console we get nothing

Comment: @MilanSachani Yeah I had a typo in the code. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

just add the below snippet:

```
const newArr = arr.map(data => {
    return { demo : data?.demo.filter(d => d.id != "NOT") }
})
console.log(newArr)
```

Explanation :
Here, I'm looping through each main array, entering into objects, and then filtering only those with id other than "NOT".

Comment if you stuck with anything in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding after looking in your code, You want to filter out the object which contains `id` as `NOT`. If Yes, You can simply achieve that by using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var arr = [
      {
        demo: [
          {
            label: "NOT - Notification",
            id: "NOT",
            subTree: null,
          },
          { 
            label: "LIM - Limitation", 
            id: "LIM", 
            subTree: null 
          },
        ],
  }];
  
const res = arr.map(({ demo }) => demo.filter(({ id }) => id !== 'NOT'));

console.log(res);
```